# What causes the class 'App\Role' not found error in this Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a **[Laravel 8 application](https://github.com/Ajax30/Larablog/tree/user_roles)** (link to GitHub repo) that requires user registration and login.

I am currently working on adding user roles and permissions. I have 3 roles: Admin, Author and Member. Each has its access to a section of the dashboard.

In `routes\web.php` I have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/dashboard/profile', [UserProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/dashboard/profile/update', [UserProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}/{fileName}', [UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');

    //User roles
    Route::get('/dashboard/author', [AuthorController::class, 'index']);
});
```

In `Controllers\Dashboard\AuthorController.php` I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthorController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('role:ROLE_Author');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('dasboard.author');
    }
}
```

The User class, in `app\Models\User.php` looks like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
      if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
        return true;
      }
      abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
      if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
          if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
      if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
}
```

#### The problem

Whenever I go to the route dedicated to the author, instead of loading the author's view (`views\dashboard\author.blade.php`), the browser throws the error

```
Class 'App\Role' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Models in Laravel 8 are typically in `app\Models`, and the associated namespace should be `namespace App\Models;`. Secondly, if you try to access `Role::whatever` or `new Role()`, etc without including `use App\Models\Role;` at the top of your file, it will fail. Or you can do `App\Models\Role::whatever()` without importing.

Comment: In your case, the error is likely from `->belongsToMany('App\Role');`. This should be `->belongsToMany(Role::class);`. If your `User.php` is in the same folder and has the same namespace, you don't need to import it. If it isn't, then you need to include `use App\Models\Role;`, or `->belongsToMany(App\Models\Role::class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that your `User` model is located at `app/Models`, you probably have to use `\App\Models\Role`.

Personally I like to use the class constant, so I can't make this mistake. Like this:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Comment: Where does this method belong?

Comment: If `Role.php` and `User.php` have the same namespace (`App\Models`), then you don't need `\App\Models\;`, `->belongsToMany(Role::class)` works just fine :)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir In the User class